# Форма регистрации. С помощью чего ее грамотно делать?

Tags: android

В приложении есть функции регистрации, нужно чтобы при первом запуске пользователь ввел свои данные, они отправились на сервер.

Есть несколько вариантов как сделать форму регистрации:

1. Отдельное активити
2. Фрагмент
3. С помощью алерт диалога(добавить свой layout)

Как сделать грамотно и почему именно так?

Как обычно делаете ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целом, это не имеет особого значения, однако вот некоторые идеи по этому поводу:

- **Диалог** обычно используется для получении какой-то информации от пользователя, ненадолго прерывая основное взаимодействие пользователя с программой. Юзер может в любой момент тапнуть вне диалога и вернутся к незаконченным делам в приложении. Кроме того, могут возникнуть трудности с изменением цвета, размера диалога и т.д. (возможно, придется делать свой кастомный). В вашем случае, Вы запрашиваете данные пользователя при запуске приложения, пока пользователь еще не начал работу с приложением, поэтому я не вижу причин использовать диалог.
- **Фрагмент** обычно в программе не один и применяется для быстрого переключениями между экранами приложения (не меняя при этом `Activity`). Имеет смысл, если у всех экранов апликации есть что-то общее, например, `Toolbar`.
- Отдельная **Activity** - самый простой вариант. Экраны авторизации обычно не имеют `ActionBar`-а и состоят только из нескольких полей ввода и двух-трех кнопок. Если остальные экраны приложения имеют другую, но идентичную между собой структуру, **рекомендую использовать две активити - одну для логина, другую для всего остального.** В основной активити, таким образом, можно устроить какую-нибудь навигацию, например, табы, или `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Все конструктивно и понятно!